# WordPress 3.5 Media Uploader Multiple File Select

Tags: jquery, wordpress, file-upload, wordpress-theming, media

I'm building a WordPress theme with a custom settings page. Some of the settings require the user to upload/add a set of images (more than 1). The default behavior of the media uploader is to upload and/or select a single image and insert it into a post.

I've followed [this excellent guide](https://github.com/thomasgriffin/New-Media-Image-Uploader/blob/master/js/media.js) on utilizing the media uploader, and it suggests that I should be able to set multiple to true, but it still only allows for a single file to be uploaded or selected.

Here's my code:

Load in the needed scripts since this is a custom settings page:

```
if(function_exists( 'wp_enqueue_media' )){
    wp_enqueue_media();
}else{
    wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
    wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
    wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
}
```

Javascript/jQuery For displaying the media uploader and handling the selected images:

```
var tgm_media_frame;

$('.upload-images').click(function() {

  if ( tgm_media_frame ) {
    tgm_media_frame.open();
    return;
  }

  tgm_media_frame = wp.media.frames.tgm_media_frame = wp.media({
    multiple: true,
    library: {
      type: 'image'
    },
  });

  tgm_media_frame.on('select', function(){
    var selection = tgm_media_frame.state().get('selection');
    selection.map( function( attachment ) {
      attachment = attachment.toJSON();
          console.log(attachment);
          // Do something with attachment.id and/or attachment.url here
    });
  });

  tgm_media_frame.open();

});
```

Has anyone been able to get multiple file selection working properly? Am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update**

I think media uploader has been updated since question asked and answered.  I guess in previous version of wordpress `multiple: 'add'` option was not present as suggested by other users. I'm not sure enough.

---

Everything's good with your code. Just a small part missing.

```
selection.map( function( attachment ) {
    attachment = attachment.toJSON();
    $("#something").after("<img src=" +attachment.url+">");
});
```

After `attachment` converted `toJSON` you can use it as mentioned in documentation. You can place image urls into some hidden fields posting to server and display selected images to user same time.

Just a small thing I feel weird is that, we need to press  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> to select images. It should be rather checkboxes or something.

---

**update**

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> or <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> for selecting multiple images is the way wordpress have given. For a closer look, open

> ...\wp-includes\js\media-views.js

There's a function defined  - `toggleSelectionHandler`. It listens for key combination user has pressed and accordingly calls other function which changes certain classes and cause actual selection.

After inspecting into firbug, you can see two classes are applied --

1. `selected`
2. `details`

`details` class defines styles for current clicked/active selection ( with blue thick border) and `selected` actually marks image as selected and returns it in *selection* array.

You can alter that behaviour either from that file itself or write your own function to handle selection. First approach is not good though.

*PS* :  Wordpress does not actually use above file. It chooses compressed version of same file. So you might want to load uncompressed file and play around. You can force wordpress to use uncompressed js files by setting

```
define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);
```

in `wp-config.php`. This will skip behaviour of `load-scripts.php` (loading compressed 
version of every js file into single file by merging them ).

Comment: Thanks for the info SachinG, I had no idea you had to press Shift+click to select multiple images in the media uploader. I already have code implemented in place of "DO something" that works when I select multiple images. I just wish people didn't have to hold down shift and click to do it! Guess there's no other way then?

Comment: Can we see a version that doesn't involve modifying WP Core files?

Comment: @TomJNowell There's no need to modify core files. You just have to write js handlers for above classes. Like on click of every item, change class to `selected`. I haven't tried this but it's surely possible. (:

Comment: Doesn't that merely make it look like its selected rather than actually selecting it and modifying the internal state though?

Comment: @TomJNowell Well I haven't gone through all the code but what WP *might* be doing here is, it adds class `selected` to certain element and as WP uses `backbone.js` it might be having models and collections for handling collection further. So it might be adding `selected` elements into model and creates a collection to process it further. I would like to explore and try that myself in spare time.

Answer (score 15):

You just need to change `multiple:true` to `multiple:'add'`. This is how default Create Gallery works.

Comment: This is simply the correct answer.
`multiple: "toggle"` could be of interest too.

Comment: I think media uploader has been updated since question asked and answered. I guess this option was not present in previous version of wordpress.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Awesome :)

Comment: never thought it is such a simple solution - thanks so much -- anyone knows where this is documented ?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone wants to know how to do this, one way is this. Note that it will completely override the default behavior within the scope it is implemented.

```
wp.media.view.Attachment.prototype.toggleSelectionHandler = function( event ) {
    var method = 'between';
    if ( event.shiftKey ) {
        method = 'between';
    } else {
        method = 'toggle';
    }

    this.toggleSelection({
        method: method
    });
};
```

If `multiple` is set to `true` then this will allow you to select multiple items, like in the gallery screen.

Comment: Just one word - "Perfect!"