# Getting Jquery variable to reset each time click function executes

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a question that's basically a follow up to this one:  [WordPress 3.5 Media Uploader Multiple File Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473885/wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-multiple-file-select)

I'm using [this code](https://github.com/thomasgriffin/New-Media-Image-Uploader/blob/master/js/media.js) to use Wordpress's Media uploader in a plugin admin script that requires three separate text boxes for image uploading. I've edited the code as follows so that it returns the image url into the value of the appropriate text box.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var tgm_media_frame;
    var field;
    var buttonID;
    var button;

    jQuery('.upload-images').click(function() {

        if ( tgm_media_frame ) {
            tgm_media_frame.open();
            return;
        }

        buttonID = jQuery(this).attr('id');
        button = jQuery("#"+buttonID);
        field = button.prev('input');

        tgm_media_frame = wp.media.frames.tgm_media_frame = wp.media({
            multiple: true,
            library: {
                type: 'image'
            },
        });

        tgm_media_frame.on('select', function(){
            var selection = tgm_media_frame.state().get('selection');
            selection.map( function( attachment ) {
                attachment = attachment.toJSON();
                console.log(field.attr('id'));
                field.val(attachment.url);
            });
        });

        tgm_media_frame.open();

    });

});
```

When I click the first button and upoad an image, it works as expected. However, when I click a different button of the same class to upload the next image, the uploader works, but the url is placed in the input field for the first button. Once the field variable is set the first time, it doesn't change. How do I get it to reset after each click so that the URL goes into the appropriate input text field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easy to understand what's going on without JSFiddle. Maybe remove this part?

```
if ( tgm_media_frame ) {
    tgm_media_frame.open();
    return;
}
```

Comment: well, you have "var tgm_media_frame;" outside the function, so it persists when the function ends. The bit of code I recommended you remove is checking the variable to see if its empty, and if it is not empty, it will .open() and quit your function;

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to have id respective to buttons field id="field_buttonId" then you can easily get the field selector instead of prev.

buttonID = jQuery(this).attr('id');
 button = jQuery("#"+buttonID);

--> field = jQuery("#field_"+buttonID);

Comment: or even better, replace all three of those lines with simply  `field = jQuery(this).prev('input');`